# Wait 1-2 sec for fetching data from Firebase before data show up(IOS)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i create app that have information page of user and i am using Firebase Realtime Database for retrieving data. I retrieve all data but i have to wait 1 - 2 second until information show up.

what i should do to fix this problem?

this is how i read data from firebase

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getUserDetails()
}

func getUserDetails () {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users/Sellers/\(userID)/user_info/")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            self.userIDText.text = value?["userID"] as? String ?? ""
            self.userIDText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

            self.changeNameText.text = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.changeNameText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

            self.addressText.text = value?["address"] as? String ?? ""
            self.addressText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

            self.emailText.text = value?["email"] as? String ?? ""
            self.emailText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

            self.phoneNumberText.text = value?["phone_number"] as? String ?? ""
            self.phoneNumberText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is the info of the app user, could you get the value (snapshot.value) earlier, for instance in appDidFinishLaunching, store this value. And use it to load textFields in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: @claude31 do u have some example which part of the code i should put in appDidFinishLaunching and how to use it to load textFields in viewDidLoad?

Comment: You could create a global var      var userDic: NSDictionary?   Then, in finishLaunching, call a modified getUserDetails                                                         func getUserDetails () {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users/Sellers/\(userID)/user_info/")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            userDic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
In viewDidLoad, just use it           self.userIDText.text = userDic?["userID"] as? String ?? ""

Comment: @ Thanakorn  To make it clearer, I will post code in Answer section, even though I could not test for it

Comment: I can't see your problem; you're trying to fetch some data from a remote source that uses network, **of course** you will wait some time, every app does it and every app just shows a progress view; there could be a caching system to speed up your loadings but still you can't expect that all your remote calls are executed instantaneously

Comment: I have experimented with facebook app and no need to wait. the information it show immediately without  progress view i'm not sure how to do this or they save it in UserDefaults. If I solve the problem with the progress view, which should I enter the progress view code? @RicoCrescenzio

Answer (score 0):

Create the global var, outside of class.
Change ViewController as follows.
Note: I do not see where you defined ref.

```
var userDic: NSDictionary?

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.userIDText.text = userDic?["userID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.userIDText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        self.changeNameText.text = userDic?["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.changeNameText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        self.addressText.text = userDic?["address"] as? String ?? ""
        self.addressText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        self.emailText.text = userDic?["email"] as? String ?? ""
        self.emailText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        self.phoneNumberText.text = userDic?["phone_number"] as? String ?? ""
        self.phoneNumberText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

}
```

In AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func getUserDetails () {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users/Sellers/\(userID)/user_info/")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            userDic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        getUserDetails()
        return true // Could test if userDic != nil
    }
```

Comment: It's crash and error like this

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'

Comment: i'm glad that u try to help my 
var ref: DatabaseReference!